# The ways to increase "select" from db table with 8.000.000 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

Hellow, wrold!

I have read about that in web, but I have not found suitable solutions. I am not pro in sql, and I have the simplest table which contains 10 columns, 8.000.000 rows and the simplest query (i am working with php)

```
SELECT `field_name_1`, `field_name_2`, `field_name_3`
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `some_field`=#here_is_an_integer#
ORDER BY `some_field`
LIMIT 10;
```

Maybe some indexes, caching, or something like this.

If you have some minds about that, I'll be glad you help or just say the way I should follow to find the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Is some_field indexed?

Comment: What's the actual question? Are you trying to optimize the time execution of the above query? the `some_field` must have an index

Comment: @jarlh, no, noone

Comment: @AdamBubela, yes, I want to increase the speed of the execution time

Comment: Perhaps you want to _decrease_ the execution time... If so, create an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can formalize your question a bit better (maybe with the use of a question mark somewhere).

Anyways, if you want to increase the speed of a select on a single table such as the one you describe then at the very least the column involved in the WHERE clause should have a proper index. This could be just a standard 'KEY (`some_field`)' if it is an integer type, otherwise if it is a string (i.e varchar or varbinary) type field with a reasonable amount of cardinality within the first *n* bytes you can use a prefix index and do something like 'KEY (`some_field`(8))' and minimize the index size (subsequently increasing performance by decreasing btree search time).

Ideally the server will have enough ram (and have a large enough innodb_buffer_pool_size if you are using innodb) to keep the aforementioned index in memory. Also look into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_adaptive_hash_index
... if your server has the available resources and your application has the data access patterns to justify it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use index on `some_field` and in the best way on all columns where you use SQL `WHERE`.
If you only want to show data, use pagination on Sql with `LIMIT`
And like Admin set caching and others Mysql (or MariaDB) limits for better searching like in there ([Top 20+ MySQL Best Practices](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855))

... simple answer, if you have space available, from
MySQL> ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX ( `some_field` );

Comment: Tell me please, what kind of indexes?

Comment: You select the index type by the type of stored data and the structure of the table, please see: [Indexes Explain](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm) Unique index is for column where 2 row are not identical, thats mean, then you use in most cases normal index

Answer (score 1):

Here is things to think about:

- Make sure all fields that will be joined, WHERE or ORDER / GROUP BY have appropriate indexes (unique or just plain text)
- With many rows in a table, the memory cache of the server must be able to store the temporary resultset.
- Use InnoDb for slower inserts and faster selects, and tune InnoDb to be able to store the temporary resultset
- Do not use RAND() so that a resultset can be query-cached.
- Filter early; try to put conditions on JOIN .. AND x=y, instead of on the final WHERE condition (unless of course it is about the main table). (inner) join in the most optimal order; if you have many users and little reports for example, start by selecting the users first, limiting the number of rows immediately before doing other joins.